# Форматирование кода в phpStorm при передаче аргумента-массива в функцию

Tags: php, phpstorm, форматирование-кода

Мне нужно, чтобы это:

```
myFunction([
    'name' => 'arg1', 
    'name' => 'arg2',
]);
```

при применении автоформатирования не становилось этим:

```
myFunction(
    [
        'name' => 'arg1', 
        'name' => 'arg2',
    ]
);
```

И в то же время, мне нужно сохранить стандартное форматирование для остального кода.

Может, есть какой-то плагин, который позволит применять к определенным фрагментам кода (по шаблону) особое форматирование?

Версия phpStorm 2021.1.4.

Comment: А через стандартные нсатройки нельзя так сделать? `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP`

Answer (score 0):

Настройки Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping && Braces

Настройка "Function/constructor call argument". Должны быть **сняты** галочки

[image: Function/constructor call argument]

Настройка "Array initializer". Должны быть **установлены** следующие галочки

[image: Array initializer]

Comment: Это изменит форматирование для **всего** кода, а мне нужно особое форматирование только для случая, указанного в вопросе. Хотя, думаю, опция _Treat multiline arrays/anonymous functions as multiline arguments_ то что нужно, но в моей версии (2021.1.4) этой опции нет.

Comment: @user69 странно. Именно в этой версии я делал скриншоты